# Loop through alphabetical array for an A-Z Index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach, while-loop

This has been asked a couple times but none of the examples show it with proper HTML styling. I'm having some trouble getting the below code to wrap the items in `<ul></ul>` for each section. My current code does the `while` loop infinitely before switching letters and I'm not sure how to properly do it.

Here is my current code:

```
$range = range('A', 'Z');
if (!empty($terms)) {
  foreach ($range as $letter) {
    echo '<div class="column">';
      echo '<h3>' . $letter . '</h3>';
      echo '<ul>';
      foreach ($terms as $term) {
        while (strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1)) == $letter) {
          echo '<li><a href="' . home_url(get_term_link($term->term_id)) . '">' . $term->name  . '</a></li>';
        }
      }
      echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
<div class="column">
  <h3>A</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Atom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Awesome</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="column">
   <h3>B</h3>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Bottle</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="column">
   <h3>C</h3>
   <p>No item found</p>
</div>

[...]
```

Comment: So whats it doing wrong?

Comment: May the force be with you, if you could just use sort() method before?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: Returning the same `echo '<li><a href="' . home_url(get_term_link($term->term_id)) . '">' . $term->name  . '</a></li>';` x1000 times and breaking the page load.

Comment: The sorting is fine-- I just need it to not infinite loop under the `while` loop and only do it once for each `$term`.

Comment: I would suggest using `ORDER BY` in the query that generates `$terms` .... I am assuming it is built from a database!

Comment: `while (strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1)) == $letter)` ... this loops infinitly, because you are not going further in your `$terms` array...

Comment: @RiggsFolly The array it's self is already sorted alphabetically by name (`$term->name`)-- and orders properly without the while loop, but I need some type of loop there so I can wrap the i items in a `<div></div>` and `<ul></ul>`. -- Also I realize that @Fabian but I'm unsure how to fix it to do what I want properly. :(

Comment: Then you dont need that `range` stuff at all

Comment: I did range because I want empty letters as well to complete the "index/glossary"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just fully changed the code as there are some performance issues with it as well mainly noted by @RiggsFolly, and I agree. If you want to look at the old code look in the edit history.

```
if (!empty($terms)) {
  foreach($terms as $term){
    $data[strtoupper($term->name[0])][] = '<li><a href="' . home_url(get_term_link($term->term_id)) . '">' . $term->name  . '</a></li>';
  }

  foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $letter){
    echo '<div class="column">';
    echo '<h3>' . $letter . '</h3>';
    if(isset($data[$letter])){ 
      echo '<ul>' . implode('', $data[$letter]) . '</ul>';
    } else {
      echo '<p>No item found</p>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

First we filter out the data, looping over every term name putting it in a separate array. This means we're sorting it out once, instead of doing it  26 times. This is added on a per key basis, if you have no term name match `c`, `$data['C']` is never set.

Now for the second loop; Since you also want to show letters that have no results we're gonna loop over the alphabet instead over $data and only match if the key exists or not, if it does we know we have an array result.

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to figure out how to make `<ul></ul>` not echo when the term is empty (and possibly return something such as `<p>No item found</p>` instead. I'm guessing I'll need another loop? Also I fixed my unnecessary `substr`-- thanks for that.

Comment: Seems someone is downvoting everyone on this question, but you will get the answer. Thanks a lot! Also, I moved the `<ul></ul>` inside of the `!empty($matches)` so it doesn't wrap the `<p></p>` in an unordered list. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: *"Now I'm just not sure why I got down-voted though."* - I'm asking myself that also. Jealousy maybe? Who knows; people can be rather strange animals @Xorifelse

Comment: I optimized the code a little, and thanks @Fred-ii- :)

Comment: Much appreciated. Possibly change line 13 to `!empty($matches) ? '<ul>' . implode('', $matches) . '</ul>' : '<p>No item found</p>'` so it doesn't wrap the `<p>` in  a `<ul>` when it's not found. Otherwise it's working great. :)

Comment: Hmm 26 passes over an already sorted array. Not exactly an optimized solution

Comment: I've updated the code once again, making it much more efficient as to what @RiggsFolly said.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy you don't need a while loop here

**I changed it to an IF instead**

**Here you go** :

```
$range = range('A', 'Z');
if (!empty($terms)) {
foreach ($range as $letter) {
echo '<div class="column">';
  echo '<h3>' . $letter . '</h3>';
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if (strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1)) == $letter) {
      echo '<li><a href="' . home_url(get_term_link($term->term_id)) . '">' . $term->name  . '</a></li>';
    }
  }
  echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the items you handled. if not, the while loop is infinite.

Replace `while` by an `if` condition and output should be like what you want it.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  while (strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1)) == $letter) {
    echo ...;
  }
}
```

will inner loop in the while, because you are not going forward in the `$terms` array.

Actuall, what you want is only *check*, if the letter matches, so:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  if (strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1)) == $letter) {
    echo ...;
  }
}
```

will do the trick.

Sidenote: This is not very efficient, because you loop through `$range` and then for every entry there, you loop through the `$terms`. A better solution would be, to sort your terms and only loop through them once. When they are sorted, then you can remember the last first letter, and if it changes, then you put a new heading.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```
<?php
  $terms = ["Ban","Asd","Adf","Banana"];
  sort($terms);
  $range = range('A', 'Z');
    foreach ($range as $letter) {
      echo '<div class="column">';
        echo '<h3>' . $letter . '</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($terms as $index => $term) {
          if (strtoupper(substr($term, 0, 1)) == $letter) {
            echo '<li><a href="">' . $term  . '</a></li>';
            //so you would not run the same amount again
            unset($terms[$index]);
          } else {
            //break the loop when done with that letter
            break;
          }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
      echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```